# how to create a schedule for 9 teams playing x number of games no team can play same team twice no team can play same game twice

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

I am setting up a minute to win it challenge for a party. I have 9 teams of 5 players each. Each round will be head to head challenge with one team idle per round. All games are played simultaneously. there will be stations set up with a different game at each station. Teams will rotate through each station/game.
Rules: no team will play the other team twice, no team will play the same game twice
How many games do I need to do this? How do I determine the schedule per round?

I am not a mathematics person so simpler answers or equations would be appreciated. Some of the answers I have read are over my head or are displaying complete graphs which I cannot interpret.

Comment: Do you need every pair of teams to play each other at one point? Also, is the fact that each team has five players relevant at all?

Comment: yes ideally each team would play each of the other 8 teams once. 5 players per team is likely not relevant for figuring out this problem. There are 45 people playing in total so I just evenly divided them into 9 teams of 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a $9$-round schedule. This is optimal because there are $\binom 92=36$ pairs of teams, and each round takes care of four pairs.

| ${}$ | G1 | G2 | G3 | G4 | G5 | G6 | G7 | G8 | G9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **R1** | 3/5 | 7/8 | 2/6 | 1/4 |  |  |  |  |  |
| **R2** |  | 4/6 | 8/9 | 3/7 | 2/5 |  |  |  |  |
| **R3** |  |  | 5/7 | 9/1 | 4/8 | 3/6 |  |  |  |
| **R4** |  |  |  | 6/8 | 1/2 | 5/9 | 4/7 |  |  |
| **R5** |  |  |  |  | 7/9 | 2/3 | 6/1 | 5/8 |  |
| **R6** |  |  |  |  |  | 8/1 | 3/4 | 7/2 | 6/9 |
| **R7** | 7/1 |  |  |  |  |  | 9/2 | 4/5 | 8/3 |
| **R8** | 9/4 | 8/2 |  |  |  |  |  | 1/3 | 5/6 |
| **R9** | 6/7 | 1/5 | 9/3 |  |  |  |  |  | 2/4 |

I found this using the idea presented in [Anders Kaseorg's solution to a similar scheduling problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4224205/177399), together with brute force search to find the parameters which work.

Comment: this will work thank you

Comment: @Bellacat You're welcome. If an answer is helpful, it is recommended and polite to click the green check mark next to it (you can change this if a better answer comes along later).

Comment: It's $1$am so this might be buggy reasoning...  If you could do this with $8$ games, then each team would have played each game exactly once, but there are $9$ teams which is an odd number, and it takes two to tango, so that improves it's impossible, right?

Comment: @antkam Yes, good proof! Thank you, that had been bugging me!

Comment: i had so much trust in you that i thought my $1$am reasoning must be buggy somehow.  :D  anyway the question of even no. of teams is now bugging me.  $n=4$ is impossible by exhaustive search, but what about others?  i feel the rounds and the games are (almost? exactly?) the same constraints, so it almost seems finding two solutions which are "orthogonal" in a sense.  it reminds me vaguely of several other problems but the exact connection is escaping me...

Comment: @antkam It is a little reminiscent of finding an orthogonal pair of Latin squares, but I do not think that connection is helpful. For even $n$, an $n-1$ game schedule is attainable when $n = 2$ and [8](https://pastebin.com/raw/BqADMEd5). My program exhaustively found no solutions for $n=6$, but it only checked for [this](http://tournamentscheduler.net/schedule/NzQ4ODgzNTAxMQ) sequence of partitions (the usual one, where one player sits still and the others rotate).