# 10 events, 10 teams

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

I need help scheduling an event where there are 10 activities and 10 teams. Each team plays against another team for each activity. Each team must play each activity. Ideally, they would not play against the same team twice, but hopefully play against as many teams as possible. Help scheduling this?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: If they play 10 activities then they must play 10 opponents, but there are only 9 other teams...

Comment: To follow up on Henry's comment, that means each team is going to have to play one other team twice.

Comment: That would be fine if they played an opponent twice. Could someone help with what a schedule for this would look like, or how I would go about designing this?

Comment: Can multiple pairs of teams play the same activity at the same time?

Comment: No, most activities are constrained with unique equipment so only one pairing could use at one time.

Comment: BTW, if you found any of the answers helpful, you should mark one of them as accepted to indicate your issue has been solved.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a simple solution with ten rounds.  In each round $i$:

- teams $i$ and $i + 2$ play at activity $i$,
- teams $i + 6$ and $i + 7$ play at activity $i + 1$,
- teams $i + 5$ and $i + 9$ play at activity $i + 2$,
- teams $i + 1$ and $i + 4$ play at activity $i + 3$,
- teams $i + 3$ and $i + 8$ play at activity $i + 4$,

with all values taken $\bmod 10$.

| round | act. 0 | act. 1 | act. 2 | act. 3 | act. 4 | act. 5 | act. 6 | act. 7 | act. 8 | act. 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0/2 | 6/7 | 5/9 | 1/4 | 3/8 | . | . | . | . | . |
| 1 | . | 1/3 | 7/8 | 6/0 | 2/5 | 4/9 | . | . | . | . |
| 2 | . | . | 2/4 | 8/9 | 7/1 | 3/6 | 5/0 | . | . | . |
| 3 | . | . | . | 3/5 | 9/0 | 8/2 | 4/7 | 6/1 | . | . |
| 4 | . | . | . | . | 4/6 | 0/1 | 9/3 | 5/8 | 7/2 | . |
| 5 | . | . | . | . | . | 5/7 | 1/2 | 0/4 | 6/9 | 8/3 |
| 6 | 9/4 | . | . | . | . | . | 6/8 | 2/3 | 1/5 | 7/0 |
| 7 | 8/1 | 0/5 | . | . | . | . | . | 7/9 | 3/4 | 2/6 |
| 8 | 3/7 | 9/2 | 1/6 | . | . | . | . | . | 8/0 | 4/5 |
| 9 | 5/6 | 4/8 | 0/3 | 2/7 | . | . | . | . | . | 9/1 |

Comment: Elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Number the players from $0$ to $9$.  Also, number the activities from $0$ to $9$.  For $i\neq j$, players $i$ and $j$ oppose each other in activity $i+j\pmod(10)$.  It is clear that a player never plays the same activity twice.

However, player $i$ does not play activity $2i$, and neither does player $i+5$.  So for $i=0,1,2,3,4$ players $i$ and $i+5$ meet in activity $2i$.

This can be scheduled in $10$ rounds, with $5$ different activities in each round.  Consider the $50$ matches as the vertices of a graph, where two vertices are adjacent if they are in the same activity or if they share a player.  We can schedule the matches to meet the criteria if and only if the graph can be colored with $10$ colors.  I created the matches as described above, except that I numbered from $1$ to $10$, and then ran the graph through a graph coloring program by Michael Trick that I've had forever.  The chromatic number is in fact $10$.

Here is the schedule.  The line `5 vs 9 at 3` means that player $5$ plays player $9$ at activity $3$.

```
Round 1

    5 vs 9 at 3
    7 vs 10 at 6
    3 vs 8 at 5
    4 vs 6 at 9
    1 vs 2 at 2

Round 2

    5 vs 8 at 2
    4 vs 7 at 10
    2 vs 6 at 7
    9 vs 10 at 8
    1 vs 3 at 3

Round 3

    8 vs 9 at 6
    2 vs 10 at 1
    1 vs 4 at 4
    5 vs 6 at 10
    3 vs 7 at 9

Round 4

    7 vs 8 at 4
    1 vs 5 at 5
    4 vs 10 at 3
    3 vs 6 at 8
    2 vs 9 at 10

Round 5

    2 vs 8 at 9
    3 vs 10 at 2
    4 vs 9 at 7
    1 vs 6 at 6
    5 vs 7 at 1

Round 6

    3 vs 8 at 10
    4 vs 9 at 2
    6 vs 10 at 5
    1 vs 7 at 7
    2 vs 5 at 6

Round 7

    1 vs 8 at 8
    2 vs 4 at 5
    6 vs 7 at 2
    5 vs 10 at 9
    3 vs 9 at 1

Round 8

    6 vs 8 at 3
    1 vs 9 at 9
    5 vs 10 at 4
    3 vs 4 at 6
    2 vs 7 at 8

Round 9

    6 vs 9 at 4
    1 vs 10 at 10
    4 vs 8 at 1
    2 vs 7 at 3
    3 vs 5 at 7

Round 10

    7 vs 9 at 5
    1 vs 6 at 1
    2 vs 3 at 4
    8 vs 10 at 7
    4 vs 5 at 8
```

One can visually inspect the schedule to see that all $10$ players participate in each round, and that each round comprises $5$ different activities.  The program checked that I made no error in constructing the matches; each player plays each activity once, and plays against each other player at least once.

Comment: I am trying to sketch out this schedule based on your instruction, but I'm not getting it to work. Perhaps I'm confused.

Comment: How often do you get to bust out the graph coloring program?

Comment: @MikeEarnest Very rarely.  It took me a while to find it.  Today I'm looking into what it would take to convert it to a library and make a python extension.  Not something I've done before, so it might be fun, and perhaps useful to others.

Comment: @WB1 All you need is to number the players and the activities from $1$ to $10$ and use the printed schedule.  Don't worry about the construction in the first two paragraphs unless you care about the math.  If you still have trouble, please ask me a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best schedule my computer could come up with. As mentioned in the comments, in order for everyone to play every game, they will need to repeat at least one opponent, and this schedule has everyone repeating only one opponent.

My schedule takes $11$ rounds. Certainly, at least $10$ rounds are necessary, but I do not know if $10$ rounds is actually attainable.

```
          Game 1  Game 2  Game 3  Game 4  Game 5  Game 6  Game 7  Game 8  Game 9 Game 10
Round  1 │      │   4/9 │   7/8 │       │  5/10 │       │   2/3 │   1/6 │       │       │
Round  2 │      │   1/3 │   6/9 │       │   2/8 │       │  7/10 │       │   4/5 │       │
Round  3 │  5/6 │       │       │       │   3/7 │       │   1/4 │       │  9/10 │       │
Round  4 │  3/8 │       │       │  4/10 │       │   1/2 │       │   7/9 │       │   5/6 │
Round  5 │  4/7 │  2/10 │   1/5 │       │       │   3/9 │   6/8 │       │       │       │
Round  6 │ 1/10 │   6/7 │       │   3/5 │       │   4/8 │       │       │       │   2/9 │
Round  7 │      │       │       │   2/6 │   1/9 │   5/7 │       │       │       │   3/8 │
Round  8 │      │       │       │   8/9 │   4/6 │       │       │       │   2/7 │  1/10 │
Round  9 │      │       │   2/4 │   1/7 │       │       │   5/9 │  8/10 │   3/6 │       │
Round 10 │      │       │  3/10 │       │       │       │       │   2/5 │   1/8 │   4/7 │
Round 11 │  2/9 │   5/8 │       │       │       │  6/10 │       │   3/4 │       │       │
```

I solved this by first choosing which pairs play which activity using the [method described at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament), and then turned the problem of assigning rounds to these pairs as a graph coloring problem, which I solved with a simple backtracking algorithm.

Comment: Thank you Mike!

Comment: @WB1 Sure thing; I've update my answer with a schedule that is a little more efficient.